# ImageResizing.Net behind WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, image-resizing, imageresizer

I've been evaluating [Nathanael Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166893/nathanael-jones)  amazing imaging library and plugins for some image processing services my company is building on Azure. Before acquiring a license we are testing them fully to ensure they fit in within our scenario. Do yourself a favor and check them out [Here](http://imageresizing.net/).

I'm having great success with the plugins when using them in an ASP.NET MVC web application. I'm using the Image Server functionality within a Controller that I post to from the UI. Cropping, Resizing and Simple/Advanced filters are working as expected.

The problems I am having is when I move this functionality to a WCF service as a class library within that application. The cropping and resizing work exactly as expected, however all the filtering instructions (brightness, contrast, sepia, etc...) are either being ignored or fail silently. Here is the image processing code:

```
var instructions = new ImageResizer.Instructions();

//All of these instructions work
instructions.Width = 300;
instructions.Height = 300;
instructions.Mode = ImageResizer.FitMode.Crop;
instructions.OutputFormat = ImageResizer.OutputFormat.Jpeg;
instructions.JpegQuality = 90;  
double[] cropCoordinates = {0,100,0,100};
instructions.CropRectangle = cropCoordinates;       
instructions.Mode = ImageResizer.FitMode.Crop;

//These instructions are ignored, or fail silently
instructions.Invert = true;
instructions.Saturation = -1;
instructions.Sepia = true;

var imageJob = new ImageResizer.ImageJob();

imageJob.Instructions  = instructions;
imageJob.Source = bmpSource;
imageJob.Dest = typeof(Bitmap);

imageJob.Build();
```

I've duplicated the Web.Config settings that my MVC application used to the App.Config of the class library that is using the ImageResizing packages (from Nuget).

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>

    <resizer>
        <plugins>
            <add name="SimpleFilters" />
            <add name="AdvancedFilters" />
        </plugins>
    </resizer>

</configuration>
```

And just to be sure, I've also included using statements for the main library as well as for the plugins:

```
using ImageResizer;
using ImageResizer.Plugins.AdvancedFilters;
using ImageResizer.Plugins.SimpleFilters;
```

As I mentioned, the cropping and resizing work perfectly when moved to a class library with a WCF service, but the filters are failing silently. The images are cropped and sized as instructed, but the filters are not applied to the images. I've tried several variations on installing the libraries (even including the packages on every project within my solution).

Could the fact that my WCF service is hosted as a NET.TCP Endpoint? Should I consider updating my architecture to have the imaging services powered via a Web API that the WCF service posts to?

**Updated**

I'm bypassing Web.Config/App.Config by installing plugins in code like so:

```
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Plugins.Install(new ImageResizer.Plugins.SimpleFilters.SimpleFilters());
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Plugins.Install(new ImageResizer.Plugins.AdvancedFilters.AdvancedFilters());
```

I've verified that plugins are now loaded within:

```
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Plugins
```

Am now getting the following error when **imageJob.Build();** is called:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Hoping this was another issue with configuration I've added the following using statements to the top of the class that uses ImageResizer:

```
using AForge;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using AForge.Imaging.ColorReduction;
using AForge.Imaging.ComplexFilters;
using AForge.Imaging.Textures;
```

The configuration issues are resolved but I am still getting the same error for the AForge libraries. Have opened a new question for this specific issue [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569544/configuring-imageresizing-net-programatically)

Comment: WCF Best Practice: Don't use WCF.

Comment: Off topic, but can you elaborate? Are your issues with something important like performance, or do you simply dislike working WCF (yes it can be complicated). In my scenario I have X number of .Net clients (all in Azure) that need to communicate securely with a centralized service using native .Net objects. This is all done with direct Net.TPC calls within the same Affinity Group. But if you have valid concerns, I am more than open to hearing them. And if you have an alternative architecture, please share, I would love to hear it!

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: @Phill that is the dumbest thing I've heard all day (though I have to admit, the day is young).

Comment: @JohnSaunders why because its true? WCF is a terrible technology. It causes more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Phill: dig the hole deeper. Go right ahead. Also, please post a link to the article you wrote which analyzes WCF and says in detail what's wrong with it, considering it's been around for nearly a decade, constantly evolving.

Comment: @JohnSaunders there is no hole being dug. Sorry. Have they fixed DI? Serialization with JSON? Exceptions that are meaningless to the root problem? Configuration nightmare? Speed? etc. Because as of right now, they are all still problems. Seems like MS and MS Fanboys just can't stop defending it.

Comment: Not to dogpile here, but WCF server side will not be included in .NET core (which is where all new innovation in .NET will be occurring). When support for a technology is dropped by the vendor, that *does* indicate something. @Phil's advice here is also quite good; WCF is not the ideal tool for this particular job.

Comment: @NathanaelJones: support isn't being dropped, or MS would have stated "no further investment" for WCF in .NET in general. Look at what .NET Core is addressing, and you'll see why WCF (and therefore, SOAP) is not being included, at least not in the first release.

Comment: @Phill: you are ranting. What DI problem are you talking about? Every WCF service I've worked on for the past two years has used DI, either Ninject or Unity. What JSON serialization problem are you having that nobody else has? Have you not looked at WCF since .NET 4.0 to see how the configuration has become _far_ easier? If you have a speed problem, ask the experts here to help you solve it instead of coming across in an unprofessional manner.

Comment: Vendors rarely state "no further investment" on anything, it's contrary to good business practices. .NET Full/legacy will be supported, but bugs will only be fixed when they do not present a compatibility risk. [Microsoft is switching to OData/Web API internally](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/blogs/data-driver/2014/04/wcf-data-services-and-odata.aspx), so it's pretty clear where their investment is going.

Comment: Also, phil attacked a technology. @JohnSaunders replied with a personal attack, violating [SO Rule #1](http://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). People are wrong on the internet - that's normal - don't take it personally. Gotta go back to work now.

Comment: @NathanaelJones: where do you see a personal attack?

Comment: @JohnSaunders "that is the dumbest thing I've heard all day"

Ironically, you follow it up by saying Phil is "coming across in an unprofessional manner".

Comment: @NathanaelJones: I didn't say he was a dumb person, only that he said a dumb thing. That's different. I'm told that I say dumb things all the time. And, BTW, throwing out so many unsubstantiated "facts" at once is not professional. Facts matter. In the absence of facts, silence is best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect that the configuration is not being loaded. Can you access the diagnostics page by debugging and inspecting the `ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current` instance?

You might consider configuring the software by code - creating a new Config instance and installing plugins on it, then using that for each image job.

Overall, I would definitely suggest using it as an HttpModule, the way it was intended - particularly if you want to levergage disk caching.

Comment: Nathanael, I recognize your name from the question, but it would avoid any consideration of spamming if you were to edit your answer to say you're the author of the package.

Comment: Could you go into a bit more detail about that? I answer quite a few questions here tagged [imageresizer], and I'm having difficulty understanding how my answer could be considered spamming.

Comment: I don't consider it spamming, and have upvoted it. Some consider it spamming when your affiliation is not disclosed in the post.

Comment: If the question wasn't specifically - and exclusively - about the product - I would agree with you.  As the answer stands, I'm in no way promoting anything, which is the primary reason disclosure would be required.

Comment: For what it's worth, as a 3rd party ... I agree with @NathanaelJones here. He shouldn't have to copy/paste a disclaimer for each and every answer he gives, lest it be a disincentive to participate in the community. Of course, in cases where he brings it up in the context of another unrelated question, sure ... that would make sense from an ethics perspective ... but not when it's tagged [imageresizer]

Comment: Like I said, I upvoted. But I've participated in several discussions on spamming over the years on [meta] and can inform you that some would request that he identify his affiliation when answering questions about his product.

Comment: Anyone who asks him to identify himself as the author is stupid. No one asked "hey should I use ImageRezier or should I use ImageProcessor" where he would have to identify himself so that people know why hes promoting his stuff over someone elses. In this case hes answering a support question. @JohnSaunders stop ruining SO.

Comment: @Phill: pay attention! I upvoted the answer. I was informing him that some [so] users who have taken part in discussions on spam in the past would want him to self-identify. Stop hating me, and start hating what I actually _do_ or _say_.

Comment: Thanks @NathanaelJones. You are indeed correct that the current configuration shows only basic plugins are being loaded. I've updated my solution to manage configuration of ImageResizer by code and have updated my question to include the steps I'm using. The plugins are loading now, but I am getting an error when ImageResizer attempts to use the AForge libraries. Adding using statements to the top of my class is not resolving the issue. My question is now updated with the latest info.

Comment: Is `AForge.Imaging.dll` present and of the correct version? Did you install via NuGet? You may consider opening a separate question for this issue.

Comment: Yes, it's present and the correct version. The DLLs were installed as part of the dependencies with the Nuget package for ImageResizing and the plugins. I've marked this question as answered and opened a new ticket for the AForge issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29569544/configuring-imageresizing-net-programatically