# Configuring ImageResizing.Net Programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-resizing, imageresizer

I'm using [ImageResizing.Net](http://imageresizing.net/) within a class library as part of a back-end which requires bypassing Web.Config/App.Config by installing plugins in code like so:

```
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Plugins.Install(new ImageResizer.Plugins.SimpleFilters.SimpleFilters());
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Plugins.Install(new ImageResizer.Plugins.AdvancedFilters.AdvancedFilters());
```

I've verified that plugins are loaded within:

```
ImageResizer.Configuration.Config.Current.Plugins
```

I'm getting the following error when **imageJob.Build();** is called:

> Could not load file or assembly 'AForge.Imaging, Version=2.2.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ba8ddea9676ca48b' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Hoping this could be solved by referencing the libraries directly I've added the following using statements to the top of the class that uses ImageResizer:

```
using AForge;
using AForge.Imaging;
using AForge.Imaging.Filters;
using AForge.Imaging.ColorReduction;
using AForge.Imaging.ComplexFilters;
using AForge.Imaging.Textures;
```

Am still getting the same error. I've verified that the AForge references exist in my project, are the correct version and have "Copy Local" set to "True". These references were part of the dependencies that were automatically installed with the Nuget Packages for ImageResizing & the associated plugins.

**UPDATE**

I've decided to move the image processing over to a web api since the library was not designed for this scenario. This is called out by the author of the library in the comments of [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551938/imageresizing-net-behind-wcf) . I will mark this as the answer.

Comment: Did you verify the references or the DLL on disk? If the file is present, the assembly signing may be to blame; try [Add-BindingRedirect](http://www.michael-whelan.net/nuget-add-bindingredirect/).

Comment: Can you list what you referenced?  Maybe even an excerpt from the .csproj file?

Comment: Also, if you can access that diagnostics string, a gist of that would be useful.

Comment: I've decided to move the processing over to a web api since the library was not designed for this scenario. I will update my question and mark this as the answer. @Nathanael, if you prefer you can submit this as the answer as well and I'll accept it. I have 2 days before I can accept my response.

Comment: I would suggest either pursuing the question (providing diagnostics), or closing it (if you are able).

Comment: The categories for closure do not align with anything this question would fall into. I would rather not delete as it could provide valuable info for users in the future. You as the developer of this library suggested not to use this library in the fashion I attempted in a previous post (as I detail in my answer) and I would like that knowledge available to those who may find themselves here in the future. Since I've moved on from my previous architecture I can no longer provide diagnostics without time/effort spent pursuing a direction that the highest authority on the matter advised against.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to move the image processing over to a web api since the library was not designed for this scenario. This is called out by the author of the library in the comments of [this S.O. question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551938/imageresizing-net-behind-wcf)